# InfluxDB (+Grafana): get number of records in sequence without value change

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I have a simple CI monitoring - getting data from Bamboo to InfluxDB and showing various things in Grafana.

My records in Influx looks like:

```
time          Key            result
---------------------------------------------------
xxxx1         plan-1             "Success"
xxxx2         plan-1             "Failure"
xxxx3         plan-1             "Success"
xxxx4         plan-1             "Success"
xxxx5         plan-1             "Success"
xxxx6         plan-1             "Success"
xxxx7         plan-1             "Failure"
```

What I want to measure is how many "Success" records are in a row until the "Failure". And do some min, max and other funtions on it

So in this example, I'd like to see (1, 4) + avg, min, and max on top of it

So I am trying to see are metrics like "mean 'time' to break", etc. (where 'time' is not a time but number of builds...)

Is it possible to get this from InfluxDB? Or let it calculate in Grafana? Or do I have to add these values manually by some script?

Comment: You need to calculate this Grafana end I guess, InfluxDB doesn't support this in-built. One other approach could be, use InfluxDB continuous query and write this info to another measurement, let Grafana query this new measurement